# Resetting Entity Framework Migrations then synchronizing schemas from previous migrations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Entity Framework 6.1.3 Data migrations along with code first.
I am in the process of resetting the migrations. I have deleted the migrations history table and created a new baseline snapshot of the current state of the db. Everything works fine on a new install with the following intializer:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<T>, Migrations.Configuration>(true));
```

***However, how should one deploy this reset to our customers who have an existing database?*** This fails locally when i have an existing db with the error:
There is already an object named '*****' in the database.

Does anyone have a better approach when needing to reset migrations and synchronizing schemas of existing databases?

Comment: Well, depending on the number of deployments and changes, you could take your baseline script and just comment out the stuff that exists for each. Could be tedious because your would need to compare columns, keys, indices, etc. You may also be able to enclose each database object with an existential check (If Not database object exists Then create it).

Answer (score 0):

I set out thinking I needed to reset my migrations because previous developers on my team were not using the Add-Migrations script correctly. This was causing the following error:

[image]

However, I wasn't sure how that would work out for existing customers. I didn't realize that I was able to re-scaffold my migrations. After much SO searching and trial and error, I was able to save my migrations. I first migrated to a migrations that was in a good state.

[image]

It was important to use the fully qualified name given. After trial and error I found a stable migration. I verified this by running the following:

[image]

It would succeed if EF could fully reconcile. I also had to exclude from VS project, all the migrations following the recently targeted migration. Simple shift select, right click and exclude from project.

Then I added the next migration back to the project after i updated the database. I also used the fluent API to exclude all the model changes following the currently targeted migration.

[image]

Then I incrementally re-scaffold all the broken migrations.

[image]

Then at the very end I created an idempotent script of my schema up to this point. Using the following:

[image]

My migrations are now not complaining about model mismatch and I am happy.